# Which adjectives can be built from the word "atlas"?

Tags: adjectives, terminology, neologisms

We are interested in things that are like an atlas. What are the possible adjectives that can describe such things.

Four choices that came to mind are:

1) atlantic
2) atlantian
2) atlassian
3) atlassic

Regarding "atlantic": This coincides with the proper name of the ocean between the Americas and Africa/Europe.

Regarding "atlassian": Wikipedia only knows a company called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian. I didn't find any online dictionary that would have this word.

Regarding "atlantian": Again nothing found on Wikipedia nor on any dictionary.

Regarding "atlassic": Nothing found, neither on Wikipedia nor on any online dictionary.

Comment: Please show your own research on each candidate word (each is essentially a separate question), together with dictionary definitions if available. Some resources list related words (in differing degrees of closeness), some list those nearby in an alphabetical wordlist.

Comment: Atlasesque, atlasish, or maybe try to accept a more verbose construction of language like a simile.

Comment: "We are interested in things that are like an atlas" – perhaps [**cartographic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cartographic).

Comment: It would not necessarily be _atlantian_, but possibly _atlantean_. But it doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: What about [atlantal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/atlantal): “of or relating to the atlas”? :p

Comment: What's wrong with "atlas-like"?

Comment: @Laurel That's a medical term referring to the top vertebra of the spinal column, also called the "atlas", and does not envoke a book of maps. On the other hand, OP has not specified which sense of "atlas" is meant.

Comment: Atlas was one of the Titans who tried to attack the gods on Olympus.  They failed, of course.  Atlas' punishment was to hold up the heavens for ever.  He gave his name 'Mount Atlas' in Algeria.  The standard basis for development of Greek-rooted words is to follow the Greek rules.  The genitive of Atlas is Atlantos.  From there we get an adjective by replacing '-os' with 'ikos', which comes to English as atlantic, which has already been bagged by an ocean - the atlantic one, being nearest to the homonymous mountain.  So its use as an atlassy property is awkward.  Why you you need it, please?

Comment: @Tuffy What I found so interesting was the deep underlying connections dating back to PIE between all three of Greek *Atlas* (*Ἄτλας*), both of the surprising Latin suppletive stems found in the common but highly irregular verb *fero/ferre/tuli/latum* used for carrying or bearing, and the (Northern-)English verb *thole* meaning to suffer, bear, or endure. [The Tholian Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tholian_Web) comes strangely to mind.

Comment: @Tuffy: I need it in several places of a text, referring to a type of research whose objective is the creation of an atlas.

Comment: @Marlo then I think you should stick with “cartographic” and related words.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod. Indeed, that's what I have now opted for. Thanks